# Wordpress: Custom <title> for archive pages

Tags: wordpress, post, types, title, archive

I'm having a little trouble modifying the page title for my archive pages. I have a custom post type for movies, and I can't seem to alter it. Right now it reads "Movies archive". I'd like to change it altogether to something like "Programme".

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the function your template is using to output the title of your custom post type archive.

I guess it's using either [`wp_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title) or [`get_the_archive_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) so you can try adding a filter (inside `functions.php` of your theme):

```
function movies_archive_title( $title ) {

    if(is_post_type_archive('movie'))
        return 'Programme';

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'movies_archive_title' );
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'movies_archive_title' );
```

If the page viewed is the movies archive (be sure to replace `'movie'` with the exact name of your custom post type name) then it replace the title with *Programme*.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm using Sage by Roots as a starter theme. Any other places i could look?

Comment: Seems like *Sage* uses `get_the_archive_title()`. Check the post type name: find the line with `register_post_type( 'post_type_name', ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a filter in `functions.php` like this to override the title, yet preserve the site name and title separator:

```php
function movies_archive_title( $title ) {

    $site_name = get_bloginfo();
    $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '|' );
    $sep = str_pad( $sep, 30, " ", STR_PAD_BOTH );

    if(is_post_type_archive('movie')) 
        return 'Programme'.$sep.$site_name;

    return $title;
}

// Raise priority above other plugins/themes that 
// have effect on the title with 900 (the default is 10).
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'movies_archive_title', 900 ); 
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'movies_archive_title', 900 );
```

Replace `movie` with your custom post-type name and `Programme` with the desired title in the above example.

With some plugins and themes you need to raise the priority with the `priority` parameter of the `add_filter` method or you won't see a change.