# Change page title of custom archive page that is set to the homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

First, I've reviewed a few questions (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080939/wordpress-custom-title-for-archive-pages), and also tried plugins but I can't get the below working.

I'm using an archive as my homepage;

- The archive is a custom post type of `film_kernal`.
- The label is `Kernals`.
- The homepage title is currently `Kernals Archive - [Site Title]`
- The individual custom taxonomy archive pages have a title of `[Taxonomy Term] - [Site Title]`

The taxonomy pages have the correct title however I want the homepage to just read `Home - [Site Title]`. How can this be done without changing the currently correct titles of the taxonomy term pages?

I'm using the **TwentySeventeen** theme, and the default header file seems to use `wp_head` to retrieve the title but I'm not confident on how to affect this in a child header file to get things working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use Yoast you can override the the title tag with this filter

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_film_kernal_wpseo_title');
function filter_film_kernal_wpseo_title($title) {
    if(  YOUR_CASE_HERE ) {
        $title = //your code
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my page is slightly modified so I'm currently using `get_header()` to pull in the header from either the default template or a custom template. It is the default `header.php` for me and within this the call to retrieve the actual title is using `wp_head()`. I could create one template for the homepage and one for others pages but not sure how I'd modifey it using your information above...

Comment: Are you looking for the browser tab title and not the actual page title?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. One more question are you using Yoast ore any other seo plugin?

Comment: Yes, Yoast. However I don’t seem to be able to use that to edit the browser title for my general archive title, only individual custom posts

Comment: Yoast is usually appears at the bottom when you are in edit taxonomy. I guess that the home page that you have set is a taxonomy of the current post title?

Comment: I change my answer, I post the filter you have to use in order to change the yoast title tag, mabe this helps